# How to post request body in Python directly?

Tags: python, html, post, http-post

I have the following details about a POST request

`1)The URL: "http://kuexams.org/get_results"`
`2)Request body: "htno=001111505&ecode=kuBA3_Supply_Dec_2013".`

I got this from analyzing HTTP traffic. Then I found this site where you specify these values and it reurns the response. https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/sSd7o

**I need to know how to make something similar to what [the site](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/sSd7o) does. Just post the Request body to the URL and return the data for parsing.**

**P.S:** I've tried multiple methods for POST to this site http://kuexams.org/results/3GKZ-D_QBHLWXrg7lZ2IGoKBI7lGfpSK37GNoykJ8k5UerNGYn21FN6w_R5XZ8IQVUHRb8ZYVwq-zN4BhIjusQ,,/ugresults/ug 
**Here is what I tired. It uses a different method but fails miserably.**

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import urllib
import logging
import sys
import re

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=3)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]


r = br.open('http://kuexams.org/results/06JZ4SYmTV97s4oROGuLYglPFH3XxJKAunIilJkDBV0gBxSU6YVJ_kXRL0UZb3cIjz9aFdnkYaE-T_S3ubaXPg,,/ugresults/ug')

scrape = r.read()
#print(scrape)
pattern = re.compile('=5&code=(.{5})\'')

img = pattern.findall(scrape) 
print(img)
imgstr = str()
imgstr = img[0]
print(imgstr)

br.select_form("appForm")

br.form["htno"] ='001111441'

br.form["entered_captcha"] = imgstr

response = br.submit()

print response.read()

br.back()
```

Comment: What's your problem? You didn't ask about it..

Comment: @aIKid My below code is not working and also unnecessary. I want to be able to post using the URL and request body like the website I mentioned (which is made by another Stack exchange member for testing POST).

Comment: What kind of response did you get? Is an exception raised?

Comment: @aIKid I'm not getting the result. It is just giving me the original site as if nothing has been posted. Besides why go through all this nonsense of searching for capatcha script. I got the direct POST link. It works perfectly when I test it on "https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/sSd7o" (This a a site for testing POST and other HTTP requests). But I don't know how to implement this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see post request there not using any cookie or captcha details. Its implemented only client side, So no need for storing cookie or getting captcha therefore this code will work for you. **Use requests** its cool and easy to use.

```
import requests

url='http://kuexams.org/get_results'

payload={'htno': '001111441', 'ecode': 'kuBA2_Supply_Dec_2013'}

headers={"User-Agent": "Some Cool Thing"}

r=requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload)

print r.content
```

Note that server is not accepting default User-agent by requests so i added custom one without that it won't accept POST request or might give Forbidden Error.